# Why doesn't pqxx find the public relation to my table?

Tags: c++, postgresql

I try to access a table and get a "relation" error.
What I checked

- table is in the correct schema `(insert into public.persons (name, surname, age) values ('John', 'Arryn', 45))` working
- checked information_schema, my table is in public https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTUaA.png
- I didn't use double quotes when I created the table

```
    CREATE TABLE public.persons (
            id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            name        varchar(50),
            surname       varchar(50),
            age         integer,
            job    varchar(50)
        )
```

When I execute my code, it will tell me that the relation is wrong

```
      cWorker.exec(
          "insert into public.persons (name, surname, age) values ('Hans', 'Schmidt', 49);");
```

*ERROR:  relation "public.persons" does not exist*

I'd be glad if someone could explain me what I am missing here.

Comment: Most likely your C++ code is connecting to a different database

Comment: Hi, the DB is local and there is only one. In my logs I can see that I am connection to the right DB.

Comment: Then maybe you are using a different user

Comment: I also only have 1 user currently, which I use in dbeaver as well as in the connection string. The setup is very basic, dockered postgres DB, with only 1 DB and 1 user.

Comment: Hello @a_horse_with_no_name you were right. I double checked and I was on the "postgres" db and didn't notice it. Thanks for you help.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, a "cluster" or "instance" is different from a "database".  One instance will usually have more than one database (it comes with three right out of the box).  You say there is only one, but I think you mean there is only once instance (which is certainly plausible).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is exactly what confused me in the first place. I am new to postgres and found this post very helpful https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187996/are-postgresql-clusters-and-servers-the-same-thing

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you don't need to use the "public."

```
cWorker.exec("insert into persons (name, surname, age) values ('Hans', 'Schmidt', 49);");
```

I prefer to use prepared statements:

```
std::string connectString = "dbname=" + DbName + " user=" + dbUser + " " + "password=" + dbPassword + " " + " host=" + dbHost + " " + "port=" + std::to_string(dbPort);
pqxx::result r;

connection C(connectString);

try {

    if (C.is_open()) {

        pqxx::work W{ C };

        C.prepare("test", "INSERT INTO persons(name, surname, age)VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id");
        
        std::string name = "John";
        std::string surname = "Doe";
        int age = 20;
        
        // Execute the prepared Statement
        r = W.exec_prepared("test", name, surname, age);

        // The ID of the inserted person
        int id = r[0][0].as<int>();
        
        //Finalise the Creation
        W.commit();

        // close the connection
        C.close();
        
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    // error code
}
```

That sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try to stick to the prepare() handling as it looks much cleaner to me than building strings.